# How I import this package in android?

Tags: android

I want to import this

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
```

My Libirary path is `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre\lib`
But Package Location is `C:\Users\mell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-25`

How I change this path in android?

Packages->Library->org     This is Location

Comment: Actually, your imports don't depend on where are located the Android/Java runtime environment. If you want to use apache http client, you have to add the dependency in the `dependencies` block in `build.gradle` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this inside the android{...} block inside your module level build.gradle:

```
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Comment: Thank you very much It helps for me